# Concatenating string and binary data in python

Tags: python, string, concatenation, binary-data

My goal is to write mongo queries where id is binary. I have hexadecimal data which is converted to binary string and fed to query.
my code:

```
b=binascii.a2b_hexdata('#hexadecimal string#')
query=_collection.find({'_id':b})
```

This works fine. But I want to generalize this for any query.
I tried this:

```
query_string={'a':"{'_id':"+b+"}"}
query=_collection.find(query_string)
```

This throws error. This is evident as I'm trying to concatenate binary and string(unicode) characters. So I tried decoding b with utf-8, but it throws error. Is there any way to concatenate binary and string data?

Comment: Which python version? Try `b"{'_id':"+b+b"}"`.

Comment: not a mongo guy, but just wanted to point that find takes a dict  currently, while you are now attempting to pass it a string. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @mu my question is how to concatenate binary and string data. Any ways i have edited to reflect ur request. i know that accepts dictionary.

Comment: @jepio I tried your suggestion but not working.

Comment: Cast the binary data to a string via `str` (or otherwise get a string representation of the binary data).

Comment: @JackManey plz give syntax for t your suggestion. I tried using str(binarydata) but it didn't gave expected result.

Comment: Then you'll have to find a way to convert your binary data into a string. Since I have no idea what that data is, that's as specific as I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mongo query form query as a dictionary. for ex:

```
b=binascii.hexdata('/string/')
query={'id':b}
#if you want to add another condition like a.Status
query['a.status']=/your value/
result=_collection.find(query)
```